# Flutter ListView Snaps to the Top

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I am doing a news feed for my app where it retrieves posts stored in Firestore. I am able to pull the posts fine but the issue happens when I scroll back up. For example, say item 6 and 7 are being displayed and I try to scroll up. The app literally snaps to the top after one scroll. Here is the video illustrating what I am trying to describe. The first post in the feed has the caption "Serene", notice after I scroll down and up the app jumps all the way back to "Serene".

[Video of demonstration](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GBXEOgGpPnh-0I60X9WBRSrbDfDmtcKF)

I am not sure what is causing this behaviour. Here is my code:

```
loadFeed(){
    //first get the locally saved details of the user before calling Firestore
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getUserLocally(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData) {
          User user = snapshot.data;
          print("+++ ${user.userId}");
          //once the user has been retrieved, we can now use the userId to make a
          //call to Firestore. We first retrieve all the post ids under the user's news feed
          return StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection(Constants.NEWS_FEED_NODE)
                .document(user.userId).
            collection(Constants.POSTS_NODE).orderBy("timestamp",descending: true).snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData)
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);

              if (snapshot.data.documents.length == 0)
                return Container();
              //after getting the post ids, we then make a call to FireStore again
              //to retrieve the details of the individual posts
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                    //save the snapshot of the post which has the following details:
                    //postId, userId, timeStamp, and like status
                    DocumentSnapshot shot = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                    return StreamBuilder(
                      stream: Firestore.instance.collection(Constants.USERS_NODE).
                      document(shot["user_id"]).collection(Constants.POSTS_NODE).document(shot.documentID).snapshots(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
                        if(!snap.hasData) return Container();

                        return FeedItem(feed: Feed.fireStore(
                            snapshot: snap.data),userId: user.userId,postLiked: shot["liked"],);
                      },
                    );
                    /*return FeedItem(feed: Feed.fireStore(
                        snapshot: snapshot.data.documents[index]));*/
                  });
            },
          );
        }else{
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        }
      },
    );
  }
```